# Base Adapter Position on Scroll

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have this adapter that shows items from list retrieved from a web service, upon scrolling it's inflating the first position layout (it's considering the first visible item having position 0 which is not right), please help.

here's my adapter:

```
private class hwListArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private ArrayList<HomeWork> Items;
    private final Activity context;

    public hwListArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<HomeWork> items) {

        this.context = context;
        this.Items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Items.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        TextView desc, date, course;
        if (position == 0) {

            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.homework_list_top, null);

            AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (MyApplication.screenHeight * 0.05));
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
        } else {
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.homework_list_item, null);
            }
            AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (MyApplication.screenHeight * 0.6) / 8);
            v.setLayoutParams(params);


            desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descriptionHW);
            desc.setTypeface(MyApplication.dinar);
            desc.setText(Items.get(position - 1).getDetails());

            course = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.courseHW);
            course.setTypeface(MyApplication.dinar);
            course.setText(Items.get(position - 1).getCourseName());

            date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateHW);
            date.setTypeface(MyApplication.dinar);
            date.setText(dateConverter(Items.get(position - 1).getDueDate()));


        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to override `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType` to get two different `convertView`s. E.g.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

`getViewTypeCount` says that you want to handle two different type of rows, and `getItemViewType` returns the actual type. Be aware that the return type of `getItemViewType` is used internally by android to address an array of View, so be sure to return always a value between `0` and `getViewTypeCount() -1`

Comment: so make the if like if(getItemViewType(position) == 0) ??

Comment: if you want you could do that, but it won't make much difference in this case. But yes, as general rule you should do it that way